# When clicking on like button it should show to particular data?

Tags: javascript, json, angular, ionic-framework

I have a looping structure with the data in post like content text,photos,videos what should i do for the data when clicking on the like button it should select particular like index data only.

As i am new to ionic and angular, i tried calling that data with the index i in the button click event,but it does not represent's me back anything.

```
.html file
  <ion-button fill="clear" (click)="likebutton(i)">Like {{numberoflike[i]}}</ion-button>
```

```
.ts file
  likebutton(){
    this.numberoflike++;
  }
```

I want to select any one like with the data represent's me and show to particular like button only.
if possible please let me acknowledge with the how to use *ngFor and passing inside parameter and values fof it

Answer (score 2):

You can do like this,

.ts File

```
export class MyComponent implements OnInit {
numberoflike:number[]=[];
itemsArray:number[]=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7];

    likebutton(i){
    this.numberoflike[i]++;//increment the count with given index
  }
  ngOnInit() {
    this.itemsArray.forEach(()=>this.numberoflike.push(0));//initialize the likes array
  }

}
```

.html File

```
  <ion-card type="md" *ngFor="let item of itemsArray;let i=index;"> 
        <ion-item (click)="likebutton(i)">
            Like {{numberoflike[i]}}
        </ion-item>
                 </ion-card>
```

Comment: thanks arunkumar for your quick response,but had an issue with it created looping with every structure.and took that values at other looping data's.

Comment: what is the issue?

Comment: whie calling of the itemsArray[1],it applies to every data of loop and does not push the value to single post.

Comment: why are you calling itemsArray[1]? it should be itemsArray[i] right?

Comment: at the ts side you called above the constructor itemsArray[] and i tried calling it then it applied but not getting actuall..

Comment: this is the   stackblitz link [https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-vcwgft ]
let me know any issue

Comment: perfect arunkumar,go it.

Comment: yes sure but i want to still loop with your content, was confused that while clicking on it did'nt happend.now let me try to apply the code.and thanks for your support.

Comment: arun kumar whie clicking on the button can it be both functiionalitess..?

Comment: you mean taking back the like just in facebook?

Comment: i just same as it...!

Comment: okay got it.but a little help what about like and unlike string in return..?

Comment: replace  Like {{numberoflike[i]}}

with {{(!likeStatus[i])?"Like":"Unlike"}} {{numberoflike[i]}}